# grep filename with extension from a list of URLS using [regex]

Tags: regex, grep

Hello everyone I'm working on a list of urls where I only need to grep all file names that end with .asp or .aspx and there should not be any duplicates as well so I came across this solution to remove everything before the last `/` and after `.asp`

I tried this regex which removes everything before the last `/`

`([^\/]+$)`

e.g.

`abc/abc/abc/xyz.asp` >> `xyz.asp`

But if there is a `/` after `.asp` it starts selecting after that `/`

`abc/abc/abc/xyz.asp?ijk=lmn/opq` >> `opq` which i do not want

I want to grep only strings that has `.asp` and `.aspx` and remove every single character before the last `/` and after it.

I simple words I want to grep the `filename.asp` or `filename.aspx` only

Sample Input
`https://www.redacted.com/abc/xyz.aspx?something=something`

Sample output:

```
xyz.aspx
```

Sample input:
`https://www.redacted.com/abc/xyz/file.aspx?z=x&LOC=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.redacted.com%2Fasp%2Fanotherfile-asp%2F_%2FCRID--7%2Fthirdfile.asp%3Fui%3Dhash`

sample output:

```
file.aspx, anotherfile-asp, thirdfile.asp
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do add more samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and your valuable time sir!, Just edited to add two example inputs with expected output

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, in GNU `awk` you could try following regex, along with its `match` and `RS` function used with regex.

```
awk -v RS='[^.]*[-\\.]aspx?' '
RT{
  num=split(RT,arr,"[/%2F]")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(arr[i]~/[-.]asp/){
      print arr[i]
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

If your file contains both the lines(shown in your question) then samples output will be as follows:

```
xyz.aspx
file.aspx
anotherfile-asp
thirdfile.asp
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting `RS`(record separator) as `[^.]*[-\\.]asp` for whole Input_file. Then in main program spitting records with `/%2F` and checking if any parts contains -asp OR .asp then print that matched part, like shown in sample output in above.

Comment: The expected output includes the full extension, so `.aspx` for the ones which have an `x` there.

Answer (score 1):

This is Python, but the regex should work elsewhere.

```
import re

s1 = "https://www.redacted.com/abc/xyz.aspx?something=something"
s2 = "https://www.redacted.com/abc/xyz/file.aspx?z=x&LOC=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.redacted.com%2Fasp%2Fanotherfile-asp%2F_%2FCRID--7%2Fthirdfile.asp%3Fui%3Dhash"

# We want the set of things that is not a slash, until we get to .asp or
# .aspx, followed either by ? or end of string.

name = r"[^/]*\.aspx?((?=\?)|$)"

for s in s1,s2:
    print( re.search( name, s ).group() )
```

Output:

```
xyz.aspx
file.aspx
```

Comment: The regex uses a lookaround, which is a Perl regex feature; so it works "elsewhere" only where "elsewhere" supports PCRE regex syntax. If your `grep` supports the `-P` option, try `grep -Po '[^/]*\.aspx?((?=\?)|$)' filename.txt`

Comment: @tripleee, IMHO this `grep` wouldn't catch `anotherfile-asp`, `thirdfile.asp` from 2nd line of sample.

Comment: The dot is mandatory, so the one with a dash won't work, that's true. The `x` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using `awk` and first split on the URL encoded parts that should not be part of the result.

Then from all the parts, match only the strings that do not contain `/` and end on asp with an optional x, and preceded by either `-` or `.`

```
awk '
{
  n = split($0 ,a, /(%[A-F0-9]+)+/)
  for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (match(a[i], /[^/]+[.-]aspx?/)){
      print substr(a[i], RSTART, RLENGTH)
    }
  }
}
' file
```

Output

```
file.aspx
anotherfile-asp
thirdfile.asp
xyz.aspx
```

---

If grep -P is supported, you might also use a Perl-compatible regular expression that skips the URL encoded parts:

```
grep -oP "(?:%[A-F0-9]+)+(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!%[A-F0-9])[^/])*[-.]aspx?" file
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OvtiRf/1).